Get android permissions with FRIDA timing problem
I'm trying to fetch the manifest permissions using FRIDA. My code is below and works for youtube, however I don't like the setTimeout bit. If is not there, it throws:
TypeError: cannot read property 'getApplicationContext' of null , which I presume is because it tries to get the packageInfo before app loaded.
I tried hooking into onCreate method (both on the app and the activity):
Given:
   var Application = Java.use('android.app.Application');
   var Activity = Java.use('android.app.Activity');
   var Context = Java.use('android.content.Context');

Activity.onCreate.overload('android.os.Bundle').implementation = function(bundle) { ...

Application.onCreate.overload().implementation = function () { 

however it simply does not output anything.
I also tried to go for MainActivity, whcih I didnt make it to work and it doesnt seem like a good idea too.. Any suggestions? Thanks. Full code is below:
Java.perform(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        // Load the ActivityThread class to get the current application context
        var ActivityThread = Java.use("android.app.ActivityThread");
        var app = ActivityThread.currentApplication();
        var context = app.getApplicationContext();

        // Get the package manager and the package name
        var PackageManager = Java.use("android.content.pm.PackageManager");
        var packageName = context.getPackageName();
        
        // Get the package info, which includes the permissions
        var packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS.value);
        
        // Extract and print the permissions
        var permissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions.value;
        console.log("Package: " + packageName);
        if (permissions) {
            console.log("Permissions:");
            for (var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                console.log(permissions[i]);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("No permissions found.");
        }
    }, 5000);
});



Your actual question seems to be how to get the context. I would try to hook several standard methods of Activity and Application. It doesn't have to be onCreate every other method that has access to the context and that is called after context initialization should be fine.
